# Azure AD Admin Permissions - Co owner cannot access azure active directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am new to Azure and i have been assigned rights as co admin on Azure portal.
But I am not able to view Azure Active directory.

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Can someone help where to check?

Comment: Can you provide me the details like the Url you are using to login and error you are facing while accessing the AD

Comment: [Sign in to Azure](https://portal.azure.com) and Verify [your role](https://portal.azure.com) /once you login to the portal - select the Azure active directory- in the overview you can see the assigned role of yours

Comment: I am trying to access using portal.azure.com.

{ "shellProps": { "sessionId": "15b16ee6cca34a698419fe3272985ced", "extName": "Microsoft_AAD_IAM", "contentName": "ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade", "code": 403 }, "error": { "message": "No access", "code": 403 }}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not a guest user, you should be a non-admin user of your Azure AD.

And the admin of your company has restricted access to Azure AD administration portal for non-admin user by select **Yes** here.
[image]

So there are two methods to solve this issue:

1. Add your account as admin of AAD by following [To assign a role to a
   user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-users-assign-role-azure-portal#to-assign-a-role-to-a-user).
2. If you are not allowed to be the admin of your company, the admin
   needs to close the restriction by selecting **No**, then you could
   access Azure Active directory as a non-admin user.

Comment: I believe I am not a guest user, my colleague added me as co administrator on company email address not Microsoft account.

Comment: @MasabRaghib  You and your colleague's accounts have the same domain name?

Comment: @MasabRaghib Could you please provide a screenshot of what you see when you click on Azure AD?

Comment: I have updated the original post with ErrorScreenshot.

Comment: @MasabRaghib Thanks for the screenshot. I have updated my answer.